# Textarea count + Max Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, textarea, maxlength

I'm trying to creating a little JavaScript Textcount which will include Maxarea.

Here is my JS:

```
function maxlength(item, max){
var a = $('#'+item+'').val();
var q = eval(""+a+".length");
var l = q - max
var msg = "Sorry but the max is "+max+", You have entered "+q+" characters into the textarea. Please delete at least "+l+" characters."
if (q > max){
$('#limit').html(msg);
}
}
```

With that this is the HTML:

```
<textarea id="area" onkeyup="maxlength('area', 12)"></textarea>
<br><br>
<div id="limit"></div>
```

The Problem is that the limit is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lose the eval, `var q = eval(""+a+".length");`,  and replace with this:

```
var q = a.length;
```

a is already a string with a `length` property.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxD5E/)

Comment: OK...Thank you but this doesn't fix the problem thanks for the try though. :)

Comment: You've coded it, so that the message won't show up until more than 12 characters have been typed.

Comment: Oh I see now I messed up the code because i did: var q = var q = a.length; by accident

Comment: Cool, I was getting worried I was going insane! Did that fix you issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this jQuery Plugin : http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/

I've found it to be very useful and easy to implement.